# Sum of squared differences - NumPy/Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have these 2 vectors A and B:

```
import numpy as np
A=np.array([1,2,3])
B=np.array([8,7])
```

and I want to add them up with this expression:

```
Result = sum((A-B)**2)
```

The expected result that I need is:

```
Result = np.array([X,Y])
```

Where:

```
X = (1-8)**2 + (2-8)**2 + (3-8)**2 = 110
Y = (1-7)**2 + (2-7)**2 + (3-7)**2 = 77
```

How can I do it? The 2 arrays are an example, in my case I have a very large arrays and I cannot do it manually.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make `A` a 2d array and utilize *numpy*'s broadcasting property to vectorize the calculation:

```
((A[:, None] - B) ** 2).sum(0)
# array([110,  77])
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you have mentioned that you are working with large arrays, with focus on performance here's one with [`np.einsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) that does the combined operation of `squaring` and `sum-reduction` in one step efficiently, like so -

```
def einsum_based(A,B):
    subs = A[:,None] - B
    return np.einsum('ij,ij->j',subs, subs)
```

Sample run -

```
In [16]: A = np.array([1,2,3])
    ...: B = np.array([8,7])
    ...: 

In [17]: einsum_based(A,B)
Out[17]: array([110,  77])
```

Runtime test with large arrays scaling up the given sample `1000x` -

```
In [8]: A = np.random.rand(3000)

In [9]: B = np.random.rand(2000)

In [10]: %timeit ((A[:, None] - B) ** 2).sum(0) # @Psidom's soln
10 loops, best of 3: 21 ms per loop

In [11]: %timeit einsum_based(A,B)
100 loops, best of 3: 12.3 ms per loop
```